# Taking multiple elements from an XML file and converting them into styled element

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, csv

I am a beginner (~5 months) at python and I am currently struggling in figuring out how to parse through the races that are checked off as `Yes`, convert them to a letter that represents the race, then take all of the letters and append them the new node called `multi_race`.

I was thinking of the pseudo code:

```py
node = tree.findall('race_white')
for element in elements:
    element sub ('Yes', 'A')
    element write tree to xml
```

Here is the starting XML:

```xml
<application>
    <lastname>lastname</lastname>
    <firstname>first</firstname>
    <middlename>middle</middlename>
    <sex>Male</sex>
    <BIRTH>01/01/1980</BIRTH>
    <hispanic_latino></hispanic_latino>
    <race_white>Yes</race_white>  #CodeA
    <race_black></race_black>     #CodeB
    <race_asian></race_asian>     #CodeC
    <race_american_indian></race_american_indian>  #CodeD
    <race_pacific_islander></race_pacific_islander> #CodeE
```

Here is the ending result I would like:

```xml
<application>
    <lastname>lastname</lastname>
    <firstname>first</firstname>
    <middlename>middle</middlename>
    <sex>Male</sex>  
    <BIRTH>01/01/1980</BIRTH>
    <hispanic_latino></hispanic_latino>
    <multi_race>A,</multi_race>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over all the elements of an application and for each element with a race tag, you save the corresponding letter you want to add. Once you iterated over all the tags, you can create a new element with as the tag the joined letters. Example code: (untested for now)

```
    race_to_letter_map = {
        'race_white': 'A',
        'race_black': 'B'
        # add more races
    }

    applications = tree.findall('application')
    for application in applications:
        races = []
        elements_to_delete = []
        for xml_element in application:  # iterate over all elements of application
            # check whether the current child indicates one of the races
            race_letter = race_to_letter_map.get(xml_element.tag, None)
            if race_letter is not None:
                elements_to_delete.append(xml_element)
                if xml_element.text == 'Yes':
                    races.append(race_letter)

        # removing the now unwanted tags
        for xml_element in elements_to_delete:
            application.remove(xml_element)

        # creating the resulting element and append it to application
        multi_race_element = Element('multi_race')
        multi_race_element.text = ",".join(races)
        application.append(multi_race_element)
```